# What does this say? I need help

Tags: translation

I've ordered a product from a chinese manufacturer and it has some specifications and I cannot understand some of it. I would apperciate if some of you guys here could help me out in translating it?

[image]

Comment: 3,000,000-time swing test

Comment: @MatthewButner Your questions are welcome here, but you need to give some methods that you’ve tried (OCR, google translate, etc.) to assure these questions don’t get closed.

Answer (score 0):

the literal translation is ten thousand times swing test

Comment: 300万 equals 3 million.